# Relativistic fermion on a ring

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Is it possible to have a relativistic fermion of charge -q, orbiting in a ring around a relatively heavy particle of charge +q, such that the fermion forms standing waves with n, nodes along the ring. If possible, would the system be stable and where can I find the Dirac solution for that system.

Comment: *Confined* to a ring?

Comment: Yes, confined to a ring.

Comment: I have never seen this considered. Is this a model for something physical, or just a curiosity?

Comment: There is a paper published in 2013 about a [relativistic fermion on a ring](http://downloads.hindawi.com/journals/acmp/2013/592402.pdf).